# SQLite Get constraints of a column

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

How can I get the constraints on the table's columns? or more specifically, the Unique constraint? (I managed to get notnull through `PRAGMA table_info(Users)`.

I tried doing so through `PRAGMA index_list(Users)`, but it only returned the result for the first column(it only returned one row, while the Users table contains two columns).

Maybe I miss something, I'd love some guidance. I searched throughout the internet and couldn't find anything, and it's about my first time for working with SQLite.

If it matters, I'm working on C# using System.Data.SQLite.

Comment: You do this similarly to how you would do it on other SQL engines. `select * from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='tablename'`. You were probably downvoted because this is in the SQLite docs -- though not by me. You can't use PRAGMA index because not all constraints are indexes and vice versa.

Comment: @fourwhey that only returns the tablename and the sql used to create it though.. i could try and use substrings on it, but i just wondered if there's a more efficient way to it.

Comment: Alas, there is not. You will need to parse the content for `UNIQUE`, `CONSTRAINT` etc. https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master